# Why is the console not printing first letter of a UTF-8 string in Windows 10?

Tags: c++, windows, utf-8, cmd, windows-console

I have a simple problem in a Windows console program. I wrote the following single-file (UTF-8 encoded) program in C++:

```cpp
// utf8 source file encoding
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

int main() {
    // compile and run on windows 10 and change code page to utf
    // execute from cmd.exe
    // WHY first letter 'П' - first time not printed? But after space printed?
    std::system("chcp 65001>nul");
    const char* utf8 = u8"Привет Мир";  // this will skip first letter with MinGW compiler
    const char* utf8s = u8" Привет Мир"; // this will print nice!!! Just add space
    std::cout << "cout\n";
    std::cout << utf8 << std::endl;
    std::cout << utf8s << std::endl;
    std::cout << utf8 << std::endl;
    std::cout << std::flush;
    std::wcout << L"wcout\n";
    std::wcout << L"Привет Мир" << std::endl;
    std::wcout << L" Привет Мир" << std::endl;
    std::wcout << L"Привет Мир" << std::endl;
    std::wcout << std::flush;
    std::printf("printf\n");
    std::printf("%s\n", utf8);
    std::printf("%s\n", utf8s);
    std::printf("wprintf\n");
    std::wprintf(L"Привет Мир\n");
    std::wprintf(L" Привет Мир\n");
    std::wprintf(L"Привет Мир\n");
    std::fflush(stdout);
    std::system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Output in the Windows console when run from CMD:
[image: from cmd.exe]

Output in the terminal when run from bash:
[image: from git-bash.exe]

The program's output is correct when run by git-bash.exe in Windows 10, but not when run by CMD in the console with Lucida Console font. It's not printing the first letter of Russian "Hello World" ("Привет Мир"), even with `chcp 65001`. I tried to compile this code with MinGW 7.1 and with MSVC 2017, but nothing changed. I know that rustc.exe (Rust Lang compiler) produces binary files that work in both the console and git-bash.exe with UTF-8 text printing. How can the same be done in a C++ program in Windows? Thanks in advance.

Comment: FYI, cmd.exe isn't printing anything. It's just waiting for your program to exit, so I edited your question to reflect how this works. The console (conhost.exe) doesn't support splitting a multibyte UTF-8 sequence across separate writes. Each write is decoded independently via `MultiByteToWideChar`, with no carry-over buffer in case of a partial sequence. So if the CRT flushes the buffer on the first byte of `"\xd0\x9f"`, you'll end up with both bytes decoded separately as the U+FFFD replacement character.

Comment: Your problem most likely is that the C++ compiler doesn't accept UTF-8 input, and is just blindly copying the data into the constant string space, compared to `rustc` actually interpreting the UTF-8 source code correctly.

Comment: If `"\xd0"` and `"\x9f"`are written separately, then the console (unlike a Unix terminal that works on a byte stream) will always decode them separately as U+FFFD characters, which will be displayed as two box glyphs with most fonts.  C/C++ runtimes have varying default buffering and flushing behavior. Sometimes for the console they may even intentionally write one character at a time. You need to attach a debugger with breakpoints on `kernelbase!WriteFile`, `kernelbase!WriteConsoleA`, and `kernelbase!WriteConsoleW` to investigate exactly what's being written.

Comment: Also, if MinGW supports this, I recommend calling `_setmode(_fileno(stdout), _O_U16TEXT)` at startup and using wide-character strings with `wcout` and `wprintf`. Do not rely on the console's UTF-8 (codepage 65001) support. It is severely broken, not only for this behavior, but prior to Windows 8 it returns the wrong number of bytes written, and in all versions you won't be able to read non-ASCII characters if you use UTF-8 for the input codepage (chcp.com sets both the input and output codepages via `SetConsoleCP` and `SetConsoleOutputCP`).

Comment: The `L"..."` strings are probably being miscoded by the compiler because it's not treating the source as UTF-8. @eryksun this is the travesty of the modern age - why hasn't Microsoft made this work when it's been working in Linux for so long? Python finally fixed this by making their console functions call the UTF-16 versions of the system IO functions. No reason why C++ couldn't provide a similar hack..

Comment: @MarkRansom, what really matters here is the first couple of lines from `std::cout`, which show the bytes "\xD0\x9F" being decoded separately by the console as characters that display as a default rectangle glyph, which is very likely U+FFFD if the CRT flushed on the first byte. I've seen this before in older versions of MSVC, so it's not unexpected. Beyond that, mixing `cout` and `wcout` or `printf` and `wprintf` on the same stream is undefined behavior.

Comment: @MarkRansom, I agree that Microsoft's console team (two full-time developers) should fix the UTF-8 support. It should support a stateful (per kernel File object), stream-like interface that allows splittling sequences across multiple reads and writes. Also, it should support reading non-ASCII input as UTF-8. What they do currently in Windows 10 is to just replace non-ASCII characters with NUL because they're incapable for some reason of encoding in a loop to fill the caller's buffer with as many UTF-8 bytes as will fit. They assume one ANSI byte per wide character code.